# Can we configure breakpoints in visual studio such that a line of code(assume as a function call) executes during every break-point?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints, code-injection

I just want to know whether we can configure(preferably in form of c# code) the break-point in visual studio 2015, such that, whenever it encounters during the process execution it must execute a line of code(like, creating an object to class or calling a function of a static class and it only applicable to that process).

I do know that on clicking on a break-point I can set the actions that it could be performed, but I do want to achieve it by code(either by communicating my requirement to debugger of visual studio or any other way) and same line must be executed by all breakpoints that i set in the current process.Thank-you in advance.

Comment: Other debuggers (`windbg` for example) allow you to run scripts when a breakpoint hits. Calling a function can be dangerous though.

Comment: @GANESH GANI, I agree with Waescher's suggestion, it is hard to achieve it in VS IDE, we could output messages to output window or call the code to break the project like Debugger.Breakp() method to stop debugging, or use the Breakpoint Actions and Tracepoints to prints a message to the Output windo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4(v=vs.140).aspx. But like your requirements, it really has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Visual Studio breakpoints. What you mean with "Actions" is called a "Tracepoint", [more details here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2013/10/10/tracepoints/).

However, it may help you to know that you can find out [whether a debugger is attached](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached(v=vs.110).aspx) and if so, perform custom logic in your code like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // call code here which gets not executed in the released version of your app
}
```

But be aware, users are able to attach debuggers as well, so be careful with what you plan to do in there.